# SSRS - Using Expressions with "If" statements and multiple parameter values

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, reporting-services, switch-statement, ssrs-2016

So I'm trying to set up some dynamic text for a report in SSRS with 4 user parameter fields and I keep running into the same error.  I'm still pretty new to SSRS and Visual Basic, so it's a bit hard to understand the error message.

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: The Value expression for the textrun 
‘Textbox2.Paragraphs[2].TextRuns[1]’ contains an error: [BC33104] 'If' operator
requires either two or three operands.
```

The 4 parameter fields are beginYear, beginMonth, endYear, & endMonth.  The following is the code I have in the expression:

```
If (bYear = eYear) And (bMonth = 1) And (eMonth = 3)
"3rd Quarter January - March " & eYear

ElseIf  (bYear = eYear) And (bMonth = 4) And (eMonth = 6)
"4th Quarter April - June " & eYear

ElseIf  (bYear = eYear) And (bMonth = 7) And (eMonth = 9)
"1st Quarter July - September " & eYear

ElseIf  (bYear = eYear) And (bMonth = 10) And (eMonth = 12)
"2nd Quarter October - December " & eYear

ElseIf  (bYear = eYear) And (bMonth = 1) And (eMonth = 12)
"Calendar Year " & eYear

ElseIf  (bYear = eYear) And (bMonth = eMonth)
eYear & " " & eMonth 

ElseIf  (((Convert.toInt32(bYear)) = (Convert.toInt32(eYear)) - 1) And (((Convert.toInt32(eYear)) = (Convert.toInt32(bYear)) + 1) And (bMonth = 7) And (eMonth = 6)
"Fiscal Year " & bYear & "-" & eYear

Else
             bMonth & " " & bYear & "-" & eMonth & " " & eYear
End If
```

So if I selected the following parameters from the report as follows (in the month parameters, I assigned numerical values to months):

```
-Begin Year=2018
-Begin Month=April
-End Year=2018
-End Month=June
```

I should see the following expression in the text box of the report => "4th Quarter April - June 2018"

Comment: Try adding Then statements...  And (eMonth = 3) Then  ... And (eMonth = 6) Then ... etc

Comment: I think you have an extra opening parenthesis in front of both of your **Converts**. Isn't your **year** already an **INT**? Why not? `((Convert.toInt32(bYear)) = (Convert.toInt32(eYear)) - 1) And ((Convert.toInt32(eYear)) = (Convert.toInt32(bYear)) + 1) And (bMonth = 7) And (eMonth = 6)`

Answer (score 0):

That is not the format of `If` in SSRS. See below:

```
=Iif(Parameters!yourParameter.Value = Parameters!yourAnotherParameter.Value, "value if true", "value if false")
```

For your case you should use `Switch`.

```
=Switch(Parameters!yourParameter.Value = Parameters!yourAnotherParameter.Value 
        AndAlso Parameters!yourParameter.Value = "something else"
        AndAlso Parameters!yourParameter.Value = "again something else", "desired output if all condition are met", 
        Parameters!yourNextParameter.Value = Parameters!yourNextAnotherParameter, "desired output if this condition is met")
```

Comment: I think your SWITCH syntax is incorrect. After a comparison there should be the result if true - maybe ` ...AndAlso Parameters!yourParameter.Value = "again something else", "something old", ` . To be fair, he did mention VB (though vaguely).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I confused myself by putting more than 1 condition in the first part of my example.